# Send email with PHP/IIS

Tags: php, iis, smtp

We're struggling with email submission via PHP. Currently we're using the following code:

```
<?php 
 ini_set('display_errors',1);
 ini_set("SMTP","smtp.gmail.com");
 ini_set("smtp_port","587");
 ini_set("auth_username","mymail_address@gmail.com");
 ini_set("auth_password","mypassword");
 

 $to      = 'mydestination_address@gmail.com';
 $subject = 'the subject';
 $message = 'hello';
 $headers = 'From: mymail_address@gmail.com';

 if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
 {
    echo "Success!";
 }else
 {
    echo "Failed.";
 }
?>
```

The outcome of the code gives the following message:

> Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
> command first. e22sm16110599edu.35 - gsmtp in
> C:\inetpub\production\mailtest.php on line 13 failed.

Please note that our application has been created with PHP using IIS.

Comment: Unless things have changed recently, `mail()` function does not support authentication or encryption. You need to use a less secure mail provider or just switch your code to Swift Mailer or PhpMailer.

Comment: What documentation are you using that mentions PHP INI directives called `auth_username` and `auth_password`? Are you using some modified third-party PHP distribution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with:

```
ini_set("SMTP","ssl://smtp.gmail.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","465");
```

Please check if your PHP installation has SSL support before use the code above.